# how to build json without escaping new line?

Tags: bash, jq

I run jq from bash and all my new lines are escaped

```
release_message="\`\`\`a\na\n\`\`\`"

query=$(jq -n \
   --arg message $release_message \
   "{text:\$message}"
);    
echo "query $query"
```

result

````
query {
  "text": "```a\\na\\n```"
}
````

How to prevent extra escape from jq?

Comment: literal linebreaks aren't allowed in JSON strings

Comment: @oguzismail right, I had misunderstood the question

Comment: your comment was still helpful though

Comment: @oguzismail You think so? Looks like OP does want `\n` in his output, just not `\\n`

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question either :D

Comment: That's the correct JSON encoding of `$release_message`. If your intent is that the release message is *already* a JSON-encoded value, your problem is that it's not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using bash, it's generally best to use single quotes unless you want string interpolation.  Consider, for example:

````
release_message='```a\na\n```'

query=$(jq -n \
   --arg message "$release_message" \
   '{text: $message }'
);    

echo "query $query"
````

You might want to consider using `$'....'`:

````
release_message=$'```a\na\n```'
````

### Using `gsub`

Depending on what your actual goals are, you might want to use `gsub`, e.g.

````
release_message='```a\na\n```'

query=$(jq -n \
   --arg message "$release_message" \
   '{text: ($message | gsub("\\n";"\n")) }'
);    

echo "query $query"
````

produces:

````
query {
  "text": "```a\\na\\n```"
}
````

Answer (score 1):

You can either encode your input in JSON yourself or let `jq` do it

- option 1 : encode yourself

  ````
  release_message='"```a\na\n```"'
  jq -n --argjson message "$release_message" '{text:$message}'
  # or :
  # echo "$release_message" | jq '{text:.}'
  ````

  Have `bash` produce a valid JSON string (note : quotes-enclosed), pass through the standard input or with `--argjson`.
- option 2 : let `jq` encode the string

  ````
  release_message='```a
  a
  ```'
  jq --arg message "$release_message" '{text:$message}'
  # or :
  # echo "$release_message" | jq -R --slurp '{text:.}'
  ````

  Have `bash` produce the literal string, pass with `--arg` or specify `--raw-input/-R` to have the input encoded in JSON, plus `--slurp` so that the multiple lines are considered as a single string.